# Updating a slice in rank3 tensorflow tensor along the third axis (Z) given a location (X,Y)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to re-implement the below function (written in numpy) using `Tensorflow 1.9.0`.

```py
def lateral_inhibition2(conv_spikes,SpikesPerNeuronAllowed):
    vbn = np.where(SpikesPerNeuronAllowed==0)
    conv_spikes[vbn[0],vbn[1],:]=0 
    return conv_spikes
```

`conv_spikes` is a binary tensor of rank `3` and `SpikesPerNeuronAllowed` is tensor of rank `2`. `conv_spikes` is a variable that indicates if a neuron in a specific location has spiked if the location contains `1` and a `0` indicates that neuron in that location hasn't spiked. `SpikesPerNeuronAllowed` variable indicates if all the neurons in a `X-Y` location along the `Z` axis are allowed to spike or not. A `1` in `SpikesPerNeuronAllowed` indicates that neurons at the corresponding `X-Y` location in `conv_spikes` and along the `Z` axis are allowed to spike. A `0` indicates that neurons at the corresponding `X-Y` location in `conv_spikes` and along the `Z` axis are not allowed to spike.

```py
conv_spikes2 = (np.random.rand(5,5,3)>=0.5).astype(np.int16)
temp2 = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(25,), p=[3./4, 1./4])
SpikesPerNeuronAllowed2 = temp2.reshape(5,5)
print(conv_spikes2[:,:,0])
print
print(conv_spikes2[:,:,1])
print
print(conv_spikes2[:,:,2])
print
print(SpikesPerNeuronAllowed2)
```

produces the following output

```py
##First slice of conv_spikes across Z-axis
[[0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]
##Second slice of conv_spikes across Z-axis
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
##Third slice of conv_spikes across Z-axis
[[0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1 1]]
##SpikesPerNeuronAllowed2
[[0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]]
```

Now, when the function is called

```py
conv_spikes2 = lateral_inhibition2(conv_spikes2,SpikesPerNeuronAllowed2)
print(conv_spikes2[:,:,0])
print
print(conv_spikes2[:,:,1])
print
print(conv_spikes2[:,:,2])
```

produces the following output

```
##First slice of conv_spikes across Z-axis
[[0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
##Second slice of conv_spikes across Z-axis
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]]
##Third slice of conv_spikes across Z-axis
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]]
```

I tried to repeat the same in Tensorflow as belows

```py
conv_spikes_tf = tf.Variable((np.random.rand(5,5,3)>=0.5).astype(np.int16))
a_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(5,5))
b_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
inter2 = tf.where(tf.equal(a_placeholder,b_placeholder))
output= sess.run(inter2,feed_dict{a_placeholder:SpikesPerNeuronAllowed2,b_placeholder:0})
print(output)
```

produces the below output

```py
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]
 [2 3]
 [2 4]
 [3 2]
 [3 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 0]
 [4 1]
 [4 2]
 [4 4]]
```

I try to update  `conv_spikes_tf` with the below code results in an error, I tried going through the manual for `scatter_nd_update` but I don't think I understood very well.

```py
update = tf.scatter_nd_update(conv_spikes_tf, output, np.zeros(output.shape[0]))
sess.run(update)

ValueError: The inner 1 dimensions of input.shape=[5,5,3] must match the inner 1 dimensions of updates.shape=[21,2]: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 2. Shapes are [3] and [2]. for 'ScatterNdUpdate_8' (op: 'ScatterNdUpdate') with input shapes: [5,5,3], [21,2], [21,2].
```

I don't understand the error message, specifically what is `inner 1 dimensions` mean and how can I achieve the above `numpy` functionality with tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last dim of `updates` in `tf.scatter_nd_update` should be 3, which is equal to the last dim of `ref`.

```
update = tf.scatter_nd_update(conv_spikes_tf, output, np.zeros(output.shape[0], 3))
```

If I understand correctly, you want to apply `SpikesPerNeuronAllowed2`(mask) to conv_spikes. A easier way is to reshape `conv_spikes` to (3,5,5) and multiply `SpikesPerNeuronAllowed2`.

I use a constant example to show the result. You can change it to `tf.Variable` as well.

```py
conv = (np.random.rand(3,5,5)>=0.5).astype(np.int32)
tmp = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(25,), p=[3./4, 1./4])
mask = tmp.reshape(5,5)
# array([[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
#         [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#         [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]],

#        [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#         [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]],

#        [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]], dtype=int32)

# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
tf_conv = tf.constant(conv, dtype=tf.int32)
tf_mask = tf.constant(mask, dtype=tf.int32)
res = tf_conv * tf_mask
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(res)
# array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

#        [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],

#        [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I am trying to use `update = tf.scatter_nd_update(conv_spikes_tf, output, np.zeros(output.shape[0], 3))` in a loop. I am obtaining values of `conv_spikes_tf, output, np.zeros(output.shape[0], 3))` from elsewhere and supply the values using `feed_dict`. I get dimension mismatch error like in question, can this be done?

Comment: Not sure you can do it in a loop, it's better to show the code. Is it a new question?